# DAX Query Tabular: How to use SUMMARIZE Function with FILTER Function, which have different columns on both functions

Tags: filter, dax, tabular, summarize

We are Using **SELECTCOLUMNS** Function for providing Alais Name, **SUMMARIZE** function for Aggregating the Data, also we are using **FILTER** function to filter data in the same query.

> **Requirement** : We want to perform Aggregation on Some other Columns and
> want to perform Filter on another column in a same query. As we can do
> in SQL, Can we do in DAX also, if yes then can you post an example?

**SQL Example:**

`select Column1 from TableName where Column2 = 'PO Flag' group by Column1`.

**DAX Example:**

```
Evaluate (    SelectColumns(     Filter (      Summarize ( 
     'Internet Sales', 
     'Product'[Model Name], 
     "Sales",SUM('Internet Sales'[Sales Amount])
     ) ,  
     'Product'[Product Name]="HL Road Tire"
     )  ,    "Product",'Product'[Model Name],    "Sales",[Sales]   )   )
```

Please help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

It could work something like this:

```
EVALUATE (    
    FILTER(
        SELECTCOLUMNS (     
            SUMMARIZE (
                'Internet Sales', 
                'Product'[Model Name], 
                "Sales", 
                CALCULATE(SUM('Internet Sales'[Sales Amount]), 'Product'[Product Name] = "HL Road Tire")), 
            "Product", [Model Name],
            "Sales", [Sales]),
        NOT (ISBLANK([Profit]))))
```

So, in this case I used the inner `CALCULATE()` to apply the filter on `Product[Product Name]`. You were trying to filter out the rows after they were already summarized, but because the column that was being filtered didn't exist in the summarized table it didn't work.